# Access column in data frame that shares a name with other columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have three different columns each named `Weight (LB)`. When I print out the column names pandas seems to distinguish between them using `Weight (LB)` and `Weight (LB).1` and `Weight (LB).2`. So I tried accessing each one individually while iterating the rows and appending their values to separate lists. I should end up with 3 lists of size 22 but instead I have 3 lists of size 66. Each list is getting all of the values in the `Weight (LB)` columns. So I switched it up and tried accessing at the specific column indexes. Surely there is no way this won't work! But I ended up in the same boat.

```
>>> for idx, row in df.iterrows():
...     squat.append(df.iloc[idx, 6])
...     if row['Exercise 2'] == 'Overhead press':
...             overhead.append(df.iloc[idx, 14])
...     else:
...             bench.append(df.iloc[idx, 14])
...     if row['Exercise 3'] == 'Deadlift':
...             deadlift.append(df.iloc[idx, 22])
...     else:
...             barbell.append(df.iloc[idx, 22])
... 
>>> len(squat)
66
```

So basically what I need help with is accessing data in the specific columns separately despite them having the same name.

Thanks!

Edit: I can access each column via the `iloc` properly but for whatever reason all of the values are getting added to each list. O_o

Edit again: I noticed that when I created the lists using `squat = bench = overhead = deadlift = barbell = []` it would yield the unexpected behavior but when I created the lists each on their own lines then it worked as expected.

Comment: To comment on your edit: `squat = bench = overhead = deadlift = barbell = []` doesn't make five new lists, it makes *one* new list, and says that all five names now refer to that list.  Just like `a = [1]; b = a; a.append(2)` will change "both" lists, because there aren't two lists, there's only one, with two names for it.

Comment: Yeah I seemed to have forgotten that when asking this question. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just rename your columns, in general it will make life a lot easier.  It's a little tricky with duplicates, but you can assign directly to the columns with some kind of mapping function like this.

```
def rename_dup(col):
    ans = []
    counter = 1
    for c in col:
        if c.startswith('Weight (LB)'):
            ans.append(c + str(counter))
            counter += 1
        else:
            ans.append(c)

    return ans

df.columns = rename_dup(df.columns)
```

Also, you may not want to be using itterrows.  Probably cleaner to write something like this:

```
overhead =  df.loc[df['Exercise 2'] == 'Overhead press', 'Weight(LB)2']
bench =  df.loc[df['Exercise 2'] != 'Overhead press', 'Weight(LB)2']
# etc...
```